# Cyclic Reference Error from parent to children module reference

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm referencing my jar dependency generated from my module build by:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hammerden</groupId>
    <artifactId>adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

My module look something like:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.hammerden</groupId>
    <artifactId>acacia</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>adapter</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I try to build the parent project I get an error

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [ERROR] [ERROR] The projects in the
>   reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between
>   'Vertex{label='org.hammerden:acacia:1.0-SNAPSHOT'}' and
>   'Vertex{label='org.hammerden:adapter:1.0-SNAPSHOT'}' introduces to
>   cycle in the graph org.hammerden:adapter:1.0-SNAPSHOT -->
>   org.hammerden:acacia:1.0-SNAPSHOT -->
>   org.hammerden:adapter:1.0-SNAPSHOT @

How can it find the generated jar from the children module? It seems like jar cannot be found from parent.

Comment: A parent should never have a dependency to a child. What are you trying to do? A parent should never have code which needs a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Maven: The Complete Reference, 3.6.2. Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit):

[image: Figure 3.4. maven-book Multi-module vs. Inheritance]

There is a good reason why the red arrows point into one direction only: Inheritance.